# When editting git notes, lines start with # disappear?

Tags: git

If I use `git notes --ref=$REF edit $COMMIT`,original message is:

Notes (xxx):

```
#NEW

path/to/file1: your message

path/to/file2: your message

#TEST

path/to/file3: your message
```

then the message becomes

Notes (xxx):

```
path/to/file1: your message

path/to/file2: your message

path/to/file3: your message
```

How to avoid that? I want to keep "#".

Comment: @seb No. `git notes` is a different command than `git commit`, and takes different options. It doesn't appear to have a `--cleanup` option like `git commit` does.

Comment: Did anyone who voted to close this actually read the comments or the answer? This question is about the `git notes` command, not the `git commit` command, and they take different arguments, so that question is not relevant to answering this one. I cannot believe how many people blindly vote to close questions without even giving the least bit of thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at `builtin/notes.c` in Git, you will see that it calls `stripspace(&(msg->buf), 1);` if it [calls an editor](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/notes.c#L165), but `stripspace(&(msg->buf), 0);` if the message is [passed in on the command line](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/notes.c#L232) or [via a file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/notes.c#L246). [`stripspace(..., 1);`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/stripspace.c#L21) means "skip comments", which causes it to strip out comments as well (lines starting with `#`), while `stripspace(..., 0)` means "don't skip comments", so they will be included.

So it looks like the best way to create notes including a `#` at the beginning of a line is to pass the note in via `-m 'note contents'` on the command line or `-F filename` to read the note in from a file.

This applies to the latest version of the code in git.git; I've tested with 1.8.0.

Comment: I use  1.7.10.1, and `-m "contents"` & `-F file` works well. Based on your comments, the only way I can change the notes with specific format is to use `--force -m "content"` or `--force -F file`?

Comment: @Flyakite Yes, in order to edit a note using the `-m` or `-F` flags, you need to use `git notes add --force` or `-f`. If you [take a look at the implementation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/notes.c#L719) (or just try it out), you can use `git notes edit -m` or `-F`, but you will get a warning that tells you to use `add -f`.